# Flutter : How create a copy of Fture List inside Provider?

Tags: flutter, future, provider

I have provider bring a list from api :

```
get myTeam => getMyTeam();
  Future<dynamic> getMyTeam() async {
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

    var client = prefs.getString('client');
    var socialId = prefs.getString('social_id');
    var newurl = Uri.parse(url + '/get_team/$socialId/$client');
    var response = await http.get(newurl);

    return myTeamFromMap(response.body);
  }
```

now I want to make a copy of his list to update it's values then saving it again to api ,I used the myTeam in widget like this :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GeneralProvider>(
        builder: (context, generalProvider, child) {
      var items = generalProvider.myTeam;
      return FutureBuilder(
          future: items,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 85,
                      child: Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                            subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data[index].surname}'),
                            leading: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                    './assets/logos/${snapshot.data[index].surname}.png')),
                            title: Text('${snapshot.data[index].myclub}')),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            } else {
              return Text('bad');
            }
          });
    });
  }
```

---

How can I do that inside provider?

Comment: Please, it's high time you start from the basics about dart and flutter without jumping far !!

Comment: @OMiShah as I am basic can you answer my question lease